# Updating from libnet-z3950-perl to libnet-z3950-zoom-perl

Tags: package-management, 8.04

I have a server running 8.04 with the [libnet-z3950-perl](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnet-z3950-perl) package

I got some issues with encoding and while trying to debug them on my local 10.10 installation I got the following error:

```
# apt-get install libnet-z3950-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libnet-z3950-perl is not available,
but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing,
has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libnet-z3950-zoom-perl

E: Package 'libnet-z3950-perl' has no installation candidate
```

Now I want to use the [libnet-z3950-zoom-perl](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnet-z3950-zoom-perl) package, which includes the `libnet-z3950-perl` package.

My question is is the `libnet-z3950-zoom-perl` package backward compatible with `8.04`, and are there any special steps I have to take, other then downloading the package and extracting it on my server, to get it to work?

**Edit:**
I also asked on [launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnet-z3950-zoom-perl/+question/142056)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the solution on [launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnet-z3950-zoom-perl/+question/142056).